# How to detect on start event in android but not for onresume?

Tags: android

In android, is there an event which only fires when the app opened from clicking the app icon from home (like the app shouldn't have been running in the background).

I don't want to use onresume, because then if you click back to get to that activity, onresume will fire.

Thanks

Comment: There's `onCreate`, right?

Answer (score 0):

> like the app shouldn't have been running in the background

That's `onCreate`, if it shouldn't have been running in the background.

> only fires when the app opened from clicking the app icon from home

That's `onCreate`.

> because then if you click back to get to that activity, onresume will fire

`onCreate` won't do that.

---

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);  

    // do your thing

}
```